# How can I correctly create a JUnit test method testing a service method that needs a Pageable object for pagination?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-data

I have this service method that must be tested using JUnit:

```
@Override
public Page<WalletDTO> getWalletListByWalletTypes(List<String> walletTypesIds, Pageable pageable) throws NotFoundException {

    if(walletTypesIds == null) {
        Page<Wallet> walletsDTOList = this.walletRepository.findAll(pageable);
        return walletsDTOList.map(m -> conversionService.convert(m, WalletDTO.class));
    }
    List<WalletType> walletsTypesEntity = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String wt : walletTypesIds){
        //WalletType wtEntity = this.walletTypeRepository.findByName(wt);
        WalletType wtEntity = this.walletTypeRepository.findById(Integer.parseInt(wt)).get();
        if(wtEntity == null) throw new NotFoundException("WalletType not found: " + wt);
        walletsTypesEntity.add(wtEntity);
    }

    
    Page<Wallet> walletsDTOList = this.walletRepository.findByWalletTypeIn(walletsTypesEntity,pageable);
    return walletsDTOList.map(m -> conversionService.convert(m, WalletDTO.class));
    
}
```

As you can see it takes the **Pageable pageable** object as input parameter in order to page the result.

Then I created a JUnit test method like this:

```
@Test
@Order(2)
public void getWalletListByWalletTypesTest() throws NotFoundException {
    
    List<String> singleItemList = Arrays.asList("1");
    List<String> multiItemsList = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
    
    Page<WalletDTO> walletsType1DTOList =  this.walletService.getWalletListByWalletTypes(singleItemList, null);
    Page<WalletDTO> walletsAlltypesDTOList =  this.walletService.getWalletListByWalletTypes(multiItemsList, null);
    
    
    assertTrue(walletsType1DTOList.getNumberOfElements() > 0, "Exist at least one wallet");
    assertTrue(walletsAlltypesDTOList.getNumberOfElements() > 0, "Exist at least one wallet");
    assertTrue(walletsAlltypesDTOList.getNumberOfElements() < walletsType1DTOList.getNumberOfElements(), 
               "The wallets belonging to all the wallets types are > then the wallet belonging to a single wallet type");
    
}
```

But it is not working because when it call the **getWalletListByWalletTypes()** method to be tested it is passing **null** instead passing this **Pageable** parameter. So when the method is executed it thrown an exception when this line of code (when it call the repository method to retrieve data from DB) is executed:

```
Page<Wallet> walletsDTOList = this.walletRepository.findByWalletTypeIn(walletsTypesEntity,pageable);
```

it seems to me that I cannot create a **Pageable** object or I am not uderstending how.

What is the way to correctly test a method like this?

Comment: You can use `Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 20);`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways. Usually, for making unit test we use mock objects(Junit+Mockito lib) because Unit-test is a behavior test. Hence first way is just mocking Pageable class:

```
final Pageable sourcePageable = mock(Pageable.class);
```

and getting a size and a number of page by "when/then":

```
when(sourcePageable.getPageNumber()).thenReturn(1);
when(sourcePageable.getPageSize()).thenReturn(20);
```

The second way as said Dirk Deyne above is creating a type which is implementing `Pageable` interface(for example `PageRequest`)

Which of them you will use is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

for Unit Tests you can mock the dependencies which are out of scope of the tests.

I guess the most popular framework for this job in Java is Mockito

just use

```java
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class MyTest {
  
  @Test
  void testMock() {
    var pageableMock = mock(Pageable.class);
    ....
  }
}
```

if you have the return values of the mock are used you can even mock the `Pageable` methods.

```java
when(pageableMock.getPageNumber()).thenReturn(1);
when(pageableMock.getPageSize()).thenReturn(DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE);
```